# How to convert SAS Retain function to Python

Tags: python, sas, retain

I need to convert below SAS code to Python:

```
data  df1;
  set   df;
  by ID  date;
  retain  variable_1;

  if first.ID then do;
    variable_1 = 100;
  end;

  variable_1 = variable_1 * (1 - variable_2 - variable_3)

run;
```

The dataset has around 1 million IDs and each ID has 10 to 50 different date.

I've sorted the data by ID and date, then tried below function in Python:

```
df['count'] = df.groupby(['ID', 'Date'].cumcount()
df.loc[df['count']==0, 'variable_1'] = 100

for j in range(1, len(df)):
    if df.loc[j, 'count']!=0:
        df.loc[j, 'variable_1'] = (1- df.loc[j, 'variable_2'] - \
                                      df.loc [j, 'variable_3']) * \
                                   df.loc[j-1, 'variable_1']

However, it takes a very long time to finish the run.
```

Could anyone helps to suggest a faster way to do above work in Python? Very appreciate!